# How do I move the contents to the top of a Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to move text/words to the top of the box to align with the rest of the spreadsheet

Comment: Do you just mean top alignment? There is a button to do this under home

Comment: Some screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: This is the button I am referring to unless you mean something else: http://rachel.golearn.us/modules/en-GCF2015/content/collections/excel2010/2937/img/3_align_vertical.png

Comment: It would be helpful to know where exactly you expect it to be.  Your current screenshot indicates your already using top align, which means, its already should be where you want it.

Comment: It is Eric F screenshot not Tori's

Comment: @Tori - Feel free to submit your own screenshot and somebody will replace the current image.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cell you want to align, switch to the "home" tab, then click the top align button.

[image: Selecting top align]